# Abstract urls that are not part of your website in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

Say for example on your django site, you have many buttons/links that redirect someone to http://stackoverflow.com.

Instead of having to hardcode that in every time like

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
```

Is there a way abstract it so that you have one big list of urls, and you can just refer to with in your template with django tags?

```
stackoverflow = "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

```
<a href="{{ stackoverflow }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write in a view something like

```
return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

`context` is a dictionary where you can store the values you want and later refer to them in the template by `{{ your_key }}`.

You can also have a moudule where you define/add them grouped in say a `sites` dict, then you import it into the view and
do

```
from external_urls import sites
...
context.update(sites)
return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

Beaware of site name collisions with other context keys.
Maybe do instead

```
...
context['sites'] = sites
```

and use in the template

```
   {{ sites['sitename'] }}
```

You can also think in loading this `sites` through settings.